# How to get 4 images on one line and keep it responsive

Tags: html, css, image

I need to have 4 images of equal height, but variable width on one line. When the viewport gets smaller, the images have to resize accordingly **and stay on one line**

So something like this :

```
<div class="4images">
    <img src="1.jpg"/>
    <img src="2.jpg"/>
    <img src="3.jpg"/>
    <img src="4.jpg"/>  
</div>
```

What is the best CSS to use here ?

if I use

```
.4images  {
    width:100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
 }

 .4images img {
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

I do get the desired effect on a large screen, but when I get a smaller device, the last images go below the others... the idea is that they just would get smaller, stay in one row...

Please any hints how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `flex` **but avoid image to be a flex child** if you want the ratio preserved.

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
  }
.flex div {
  flex:1;
  margin:5px; /* need some space ?*/
  }
img {
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

you can also give a try to table model

```css
.table {
  border-spacing:5px; /* need some space ?*/
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
  }
.table div {
  display:table-cell;
  }
img {
  width:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to prevent the table model, but the 'flex' is perfect for the job.

Comment: @WilkovanderPloeg flex or table doesn't semanticly change the markup. display:table; includes ie8 too, flex not and it is still buggy in IE11, what matters here only which browser do you want to support ; ( CSS only styles HTML nothing more or less )

Answer (score 0):

The layout is simple and easy with CSS flexbox. This is all you need:

```
.images { display: flex; }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/yfxk92jd/)

When you establish a flex container (by applying `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to an element), several default rules go into effect. Two of these rules are `flex-direction: row` and `flex-wrap: nowrap`, which means child elements (aka, flex items) will align horizontally and not wrap.

Regarding your class value (`4images`), although starting with a digit is valid in HTML5 ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/3597276)), you would need to escape the character for it to be recognized by the CSS engine. I simply removed the number for demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

first:
<s>classes are not allowed to start with a number. For more information look 
[here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp)</s>
E: ok that was html4. Well shouldn't start with a digit since you have to escape it to work, like [here](https://mothereff.in/css-escapes).

second:
you can do it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/45ytdczk/)
css:

```
.images  {
width:100%;
}

.images img {
max-width: 24%;
width: 24%;
}
```

note: test around a bit with the width, sometimes the browser is calculating it not right and so you have to go down by 1%

Comment: Your *first* point is not correct. Your source (W3Schools) is provided outdated information. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/3597276

Comment: also, if you replace the class "images" in my jsfiddle with "4images" it doesn't work....

Comment: It's for ID's and classes (further in the answer).

Comment: This works if the images have the same width, but in my case they have different widths, see the original question.

Answer (score 0):

To make the images responsive, change your class definition like so.

```
 .4images img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
```

Comment: yes... but this is not by far a response to the question... 4 responsive images in a row!